# How do I use Ajax and Javascript to create table on button click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've spent the last several hours following different tutorials and looking at previously asked questions, but I cannot seem to get this to work for me. I have a simple HTML page as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="home.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        <script src="javascript.js"></script>
        <title>Test Web Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <h2>Buttons that do stuff</h2>
            <form action="PHP.php" method="post">
                <input type="submit" value="Create Database">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My PHP file is:

```
<? php
    $serverName = "localhost";

    //Create connection to server
    $connection = new mysqli($serverName, 'root', '');

    //Check connection to server
    if($connection->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo 'Hello World';
        createChapterDatabase();
    }

    function createChapterDatabase() {
       $sql = "CREATE TABLE Test_Table";
       executeQuery($sql);
    }


    function executeQuery(query) {
        if($connection->query($query) == TRUE) {
            echo "Database created successfully!";
        } else {
            echo "Connection failed: " + $connection->error;
        }
   }
?>
```

Now, when I open the webpage and click the button, I am brought to a page that just displays all of my PHP code. I am new to PHP, but have some experience (limited) with Javascript. I think, from what I've seen, I need to use Javascript to respond to the button click by using Ajax, but I can't seem to figure out how to do so. I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: if your seeing php in your browser your not running the code on a server with php enabled.

Comment: `<? php` - tried it without the space there?

Comment: Have you install wamp or xampp ?

Answer (score 0):

If your PHP is displaying as text in borwser, you don't have PHP installed.  The most common tag for php is http://www.wampserver.com/en/ or https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html . PHP is now installed or usable by default on Windows computers.  After you get one of those installed and running, simply navigate to "localhost".  If you end up using XAMPP just click start next to appache to get it going.  Or, if you can't figure that out, use an online IDE, like C9.io .

You can follow this tutorial if you get confused https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkSG19gQamc

Just a heads up, you can't have skype running while you have XAMPP running.

Comment: I have XAMPP running with Apache and when I hit localhost it brings up the apache page. I have my files under the `\xampp\htdocs directory`

Comment: Did you create a folder inside there and put your files in that.  You can't double click on the file... you have to navigate to localhost/[your directory]/

Comment: Additionally, the space does break php.  Use <?php